# Code Causing form to freeze

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I just want to show a legend when a value in cell is a certin value, I was using this

```
Private Sub dgDeliverys_DataBindingComplete(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles dgDeliverys.DataBindingComplete
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgDeliverys.Rows
        'condition for each row based on cell's input is put here
        If dr.Cells("isNotFound").Value = True Then
            dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            dr.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Now my grid only has a few rows in it at the time. But it seems to cause the form to freeze, any ideas?

Comment: Freeze means how long? Forever? Or for a while? and what was the row count?

Comment: Be aware that the `DataBindingComplete` event are fired multiple times. For more info, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828505/databindingcomplete-is-getting-called-multiple-times

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Only about ten rows at time max

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå What would you suggest then I only want it to happen once data has been populated

Comment: @DavidB I suggest you use the [CellPainting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) event or the [RowPrePaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: @DavidB Check my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20711908/1842065

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Why would cellpainting not be refired surley if text changes in a cell is that not painting a cell ?

Comment: Random deadlock is a problem associated with threading.  The DataBindingComplete event is a classic case where threading can blow your leg off.  Since you'd be apt to execute the dbase query on a worker thread, they are normally too slow.  Do this for a control that's bound and random deadlock is knocking on the door.  Unbinding the control first is a rock-hard requirement.

Comment: @DavidB It will, but only when the cell ends edit and changes are committed.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå can you please leave a correct answer so I can mark you up thanks

Comment: @DavidB No problem. I'll do it later as I'm quite busy right now.