# Alternative to DataGridView DataBindingComplete Event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the `DataBindingComplete` event for a DataGridView is fired whenever the contents of the data source change, or a property such as `DataSource` changes. This results in the method being called multiple times.
I am currently using the `DataBindingComplete` event to do some visual formatting to my form. For example, I make the text in the first column (column 0) appear as Row Headers and then hide that column (see code below).

```
private void grdComponents_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    { 
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdComponents.Rows)
        {
            row.HeaderCell.Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
        grdComponents.Columns[0].Visible = false;

        // do more stuff...
    }
```

It is unnecessary to execute this code more than once, and I am looking to put it into a place where that can happen. Unfortunately it didn't work when I added the snippet to the end of my form's `Load` method (after I set the `DataSource` of my DataGridView), nor did it work in the `DataSourceChanged` event.

Comment: [This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/50c4f46d-c3b8-4da7-b08f-a751dca12afd/databindingcomplete-event-is-been-called-twice) post resolved my similar issue. I set the DataMember property to a table name used in the DataSource and event now fires only once. Please note that the DataMember property is not necessary if the DataSource contains only one table, but I used it to avoid multiple firing of the event. Ref: [MSDN]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datamember(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `DataSourceChanged` event, but be aware, that it occurs only when data source is changed. Additionally, `DataBindingComplete` offers you information why it has happend - through `e.ListChangedType`:

```
Reset = 0,//     Much of the list has changed. Any listening controls should refresh all their data from the list.
ItemAdded = 1,//     An item added to the list
ItemDeleted = 2,//     An item deleted from the list.
ItemMoved = 3,//     An item moved within the list.
ItemChanged = 4,//     An item changed in the list.
PropertyDescriptorAdded = 5,//     A System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor was added, which changed the schema.
PropertyDescriptorDeleted = 6,//     A System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor was deleted, which changed the schema.
PropertyDescriptorChanged = 7//     A System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor was changed, which changed the schema.
```

According to this answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/50c4f46d-c3b8-4da7-b08f-a751dca12afd/databindingcomplete-event-is-been-called-twice
the whole thing happens because you don't have `DataMember` property set in your `dataGridView`. And you can set it only if you want to set particular table from database which is set as your `DataSource` of `dataGridView`. Other way - throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way will be just to execute this code once:

Add a flag like `Boolean isDataGridFormatted` in your form.

And check it like

```
private void grdComponents_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (this.isDataGridFormatted )
        return;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdComponents.Rows)
    {
        row.HeaderCell.Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
    grdComponents.Columns[0].Visible = false;

    // do more stuff...

    this.isDataGridFormatted  = false;         
}
```

A bit better will be to prepare your DataGridView during the form construction. As I understand your columns won't change during the course of your program but you don't want to initialize everything manually. You could load some dummy one-item(one-row) data during the initialization:

```
private void Initialize_DataGridView()
{
    // Add dummy data to generate the columns
    this.dataGridView_Items.DataContext = new Item[]{ new Item {Id = 5, Value = 6}};

    // Make your formatting
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdComponents.Rows)
    {
        row.HeaderCell.Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }

    grdComponents.Columns[0].Visible = false;

    // Reset the dummy data
    this.dataGridView_Items.DataContext = null; // Or new Item[]{};
}

...
public MyForm()
{
    Initialize();

    this.Initialize_DataGridView();   
}
```

I am not sure that exactly such code will work with dataGridView but it is close enough.

Of course an event would have been a nearly ideal solution but there's hardly any that deals with successful autogeneration of columns [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) except the `AutoGenerateColumnChanged` but that is not what we need.

While it is possible to use the [ColumnAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnadded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#feedback) - it will probably execute only once foreach of the autogenerated column, the actual implementation could become an overkill and will be even less direct than already mentioned approaches.

If you will have some time and desire you could create your own DataGridView derived class, take `Boolean isDataGridFormatted` from your form and implement all the initialization(or event hooking) inside the custom DataGridView.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have considered this before and hopefully there is still an event I can use rather than a flag (it's a little hack-y).

Comment: Well this is interesting. I added the flag and it resulted in my formatting not being displayed... The `DataBindingComplete` method gets called twice: the flagged code executes the first time but not the second, and then none of the changes from the first method call are displayed.

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code to see when it happens? Maybe  the first time is inside the Form.Initialize method? And the second is when you actually set the data? Or you somehow set it twice?

Comment: Set breakpoints inside the binding handler, before Form.Initialize and after. And see whether the binding handler will be called.