# How to convert text to specific controls in a DataGridView control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a grid view that gets a data added to it. How can I on edit then change the text values into dropdown controls and check box controls to make editing the gridview easier for a user>

Comment: Take a look at [Column Types in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: the problem I have with this that I don't have a column of ComboBoxes I just need to be able to set one cell in a DataGridView.

Comment: Set `DisplayStyle` of the combo box column to `DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing`.

Comment: Also probably you can use `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` for a cell.

Comment: You can assign a new xxxCell to any one Cell in the DGV. Note that for a 2nd cell you need to create a 2nd instnace of xxxCell. [See here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666665/how-to-add-a-combo-box-in-a-datagrid-view-for-only-one-cell-dynamically/30668004?s=5|0.5524#30668004)