# Cell Formatting In DataGridView On DataBindingComplete

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, event-handling

I am having problems with a requirement on one of my projects at work.  What I am doing is binding a datatable to a DataGridView(DGV)'s datasource.  I then loop through the DataGridView and check if the cell as either 1 * or 2 ** in its value and format those cells with a tooltip and a red background.  If I use a button event to trigger this everything works perfectly fine.  But if I want this to occur automatically when the form loads using the DataBindingComplete event it does not work correctly.  The problem was DataBindingComplete was firing multiple times.  I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828505/databindingcomplete-is-getting-called-multiple-times) which gave me a couple options to try and none worked.  Here is the code:

```
public partial class TestForm2 : Form
{
    private DataTable dt;
    private int methodCalls = 0;
    private bool isFormatted = false;

    public TestForm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buildDataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
    }

    private void TestForm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindData();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formatDataGridView();
    }

    private void bindData()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        //If this code is commented out the program will work just fine 
        //by just clicking the button

        //This was added to prevent formatDataGridView from executing more
        //than once.  Even though I unreg and rereg the event handler, the 
        //method was still being called 3 - 4 times. This successfully
        //prevented that but only the *'s were removed and no red back color
        //added to the cells.
        if(!isFormatted)
        {
            formatDataGridView();
        }
    }

    private void buildDataTable()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("col2");
        dt.Columns.Add("col3");
        dt.Columns.Add("col4");
        Random randNum = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            object[] rowItems = new object[dt.Columns.Count];

            for(int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                int number = randNum.Next(1, 20);

                if(number % 7 == 0)
                {
                    rowItems[j] = number + "*";
                }
                else if(number % 5 == 0)
                {
                    rowItems[j] = number + "**";
                }
                else
                {
                    rowItems[j] = number;
                }
            }

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = rowItems;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    private void formatDataGridView()
    {
        // I noticed that I needed to unregister the event handler to 
        // prevent DataBindingComplete from firing during the format
        dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete -= dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string originalCell;
            string reformattedCell;

            if(row.Cells["col1"].Value != null)
            {
                originalCell = row.Cells["col1"].Value.ToString();

                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    row.Cells["col1"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col1"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col1"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                else if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    row.Cells["col1"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col1"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col1"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }

            if (row.Cells["col2"].Value != null)
            {
                originalCell = row.Cells["col2"].Value.ToString();

                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    row.Cells["col2"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col2"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col2"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    row.Cells["col2"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col2"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col2"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }

            if (row.Cells["col3"].Value != null)
            {
                originalCell = row.Cells["col3"].Value.ToString();

                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    row.Cells["col3"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col3"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col3"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                else if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    row.Cells["col3"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col3"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col3"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }

            if (row.Cells["col4"].Value != null)
            {
                originalCell = row.Cells["col4"].Value.ToString();

                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    row.Cells["col4"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col4"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col4"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                else if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    row.Cells["col4"].Value = reformattedCell;
                    row.Cells["col4"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    row.Cells["col4"].ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
        }
        // Reregistering the event handler
        dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
        isFormatted = true;
        methodCalls++;
        MessageBox.Show("Method Calls: " + methodCalls);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to get around this problem but there has to be a way.  I am unfamiliar with DataBindingComplete until recently so I am sure to learn something here.  Thanks for the help everyone and helping me learn something new!

Comment: Try using the CellFormatting event instead.

Comment: What I think is going wrong is, during the DataBindEvent, you are changing some values in the grid. Then these changes are saved in the DataSource, after which the DataSource binds again with the new values, refiring the DataBindEvent.

Comment: @BartvanderDrift I believe this is the case.  If I do not unregister the dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete event handler by stating dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete -= dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete in my formatDataGridView method, the counter methodCalls reports that the method was called as many times as there were changes made.  However, I blocked this from happening by unregistering the event handler to prevent these changes from firing the event.  I also put a bool isFormatted that gets set as true once the method is called and the condition if(!isFormatted) also prevents this

Comment: So the dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete function is being called multiple times despite unbinding the function from the event?

Comment: @LarsTech I might have a solution using your method.  I just have to rewrite a few things to test it out.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @BartvanderDrift Ya despite that it gets called 3 times and still doesn't work correctly.  It only removes the ** from the cells' values and doesn't add the tooltip or the red back color. But when I use the button_Click event the function works perfectly.  I don't understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CellFormatting event handler was the route I ended up taking to resolve my issue.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        string originalCell;
        string reformattedCell;

        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "col1")
        {
            if(e.Value != null)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = 
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                originalCell = e.Value.ToString();
                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                else if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }

            }

        }

        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "col2")
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell =
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                originalCell = e.Value.ToString();
                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                else if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }

            }

        }

        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "col3")
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell =
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                originalCell = e.Value.ToString();
                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                else if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }

            }

        }

        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "col4")
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell =
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                originalCell = e.Value.ToString();
                if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 2)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("**", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 5";
                }

                else if (originalCell.Count(c => c == '*') == 1)
                {
                    reformattedCell = originalCell.Replace("*", "");

                    cell.Value = reformattedCell;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Divisible by 7";
                }

                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad it worked out. Don't forget to mark you own answer as the right one :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

- the formatting in the DataBindingComplete event, but not the value
- supply a "clean" value to display in the CellFormatting Event (e.Value) which does not change the underlying value stored in the dataviewgrid cell, just what value is passed to the painting event to show on the screen

Remember that when going through the data to set the formating, for efficiency if the types of CellStyles are limited e.g Good Result, Bad Result (my code has actually about 11 default styles) create the styles first.

Then assign them as you check you cell values and work out which style to use.

The only caveat of this is that later on if you change e.g Column = 12, Row = 4 cellstyle in some way it will affect all cells "sharing" the same default DataGridViewCellstyle.

e.g

```
            Font bFont = new Font("Calibri", defFontSize, FontStyle.Bold);       // Bold font
            Font iFont = new Font("Calibri", defFontSize, FontStyle.Italic);     // Italic font
            Font nFont = new Font("Calibri", defFontSize);                       // Normal font

            DataGridViewCellStyle dgvcsOKRESULT = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
            {
                Font = nFont,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                BackColor = Color.Green,
            };

            DataGridViewCellStyle dgvcsBADRESULT = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
            {
                Font = bFont,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                BackColor = Color.Red,
            };
```

Comment: Yes, this would make the code much more readable!  Thanks for the suggestion I will definitely use this in the future...upvoted!

Comment: For some more hard earned advice (having just completed the code!) I have ended up storing the display value in the Cells.Tag property as a string object. This means the actual CellFormating event code is just one line: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> e.Value = this.dataGridViewControl.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Tag;

Answer (score 1):

Call formatDataGridView from the bindData method and forget about the DataBinding event:

```
private void bindData()
{
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
  formatDataGridView();
}
```

Or is there a reason this is not possible?

Comment: Believe it or not this is what I tried to start with.  I kept running into problems with the tootip and back color missing, plus I was having problems preventing the CellValueChanged event from firing.  My logic was that my DGV wasn't done databinding before I attempted to format it.  So that's why I tried using the DataBindingComplete event handler to ensure that data binding was complete before I tried to format the DGV.  But oh well I guess I have decided that using the CellFormatting event is the way to go.  It seems to work as I want.  I will post my solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW for the example I used in this SO question, your answer does technically work ;)